# What is the easiest way to concatenate string list with number array in python

Tags: python

I can't believe how long I've been trying to figure out this really basic problem, and I can't seem to find the right answer here searching through the forum, so I'll just throw it out, as I'm *sure* this can be solved in a simple line of code:

I'm trying to generate some a generate a new column on my data frame with random unique identifiers of the form `q` + some 5 digit number.  So for example, one such ID would be `q12345`.

My approach so far, as been to:  (1) generate an array of numbers, and (2) a list of the same length of the `q` character, and then (3) try to combine them into a single array, which I would (4) add to my data frame. I've managed to do steps one and two quite easily, but I can't seem to get step 3 to work.

I'd be grateful for any tips on both (a) how to do step 3, as well as (b) an easier way to do this, which I'm sure I'm overlooking.

I tried the various approaches in [Concatenate string and int in python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090198/concatenate-string-and-int-in-python-3-4) and could get it to work for individual elements, but not for the entire array.

So, far, I have:

```
sample_length = 10 #for example

values = np.random.randint(low=10000, high= 15000, size = sample_length)

q = ['q'] * sample_length
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate string and int in python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090198/concatenate-string-and-int-in-python-3-4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine them into a single array using list-comprehension, like so:

```
sample_length = 10
values = np.random.randint(low=10000, high= 15000, size = sample_length)
# Do this 
column = ['q' + str(i) for i in values ]
```

In case the code above is too much to unpack for you, see this:

```
sample_length = 10
values = np.random.randint(low=10000, high= 15000, size = sample_length)
columns = []
for i in values:
     columns.append('q' + str(i))
```

Both the code snippets do the same thing.
Hope this helps...!

Answer (score -1):

```
import random as rand
print("q"+str(rand.randint(10000,100000)))
```

Comment: This answer is rather incomplete; if you intend to provide helpful answers you should take the time to work out applicable solutions, and explain them.

Answer (score -1):

A nearly one liner would be:

```
sample_length = 10
columns = ["q" + "".join(uniqueNumbers) for uniqueNumbers in list(map(lambda generatedNumbers: [str(number) for number in generatedNumbers], [random.randint(0, 9, 5) for _ in range(sample_length)]))]
```

For better readability:

```
sample_length = 10
columns = [
    "q" + "".join(uniqueNumbers) for uniqueNumbers in list(
        map(
            lambda generatedNumbers: [
                str(number) for number in generatedNumbers
            ],
            [
                random.randint(0, 9, 5) for _ in range(sample_length)
            ]
        )
    )
]
```

And in this case the id could start with a 0.

A better approach would be as follows because I guess that every number should be unique:

```
sample_length = 10
def getNumbers():
    return "".join(list(map(lambda number: str(number), random.randint(0, 9, 5))))
numbers = []
while len(numbers) != sample_length:
    newNumbers = getNumbers()
    if newNumbers not in numbers:
        numbers.append(newNumbers)
columns = ["q" + "".join(uniqueNumbers) for uniqueNumbers in numbers]
```